# Django dynamic models

Tags: django, models

I'm pretty new to Django and Python. I'm trying to create some "category-dependent" models. 
I have a Product model and i want to have category-dependent atributes. Example:

If i select "Permanent Dyes" in the category of my product i want to have specific atributes for my user to fill.

I don't want to create different models for every type of product i'm going to manage.

Is there any workaround to do this and keep using the django-admin?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Model inheritance seems like it would help in this situation. Using it, you can have an abstract `Product` base class and then use `Meta` to add different product-dependent characteristics you need. It may require different models, but you would only need to add the attributes you needed, like below

```
class Product(models.Model):
    ....

class ProductA(Product):
    class Meta:
        ....
```

This will allow you to have general properties in the Product class, such as price, etc., but use the subclass as a way to distinguish between different products.
Hope that helped in some way!